# Получение выбранного элемента в select

Tags: php, html

```
<form id="formazak" method="get">Контактная информация<br /><br />      Вы заказываете как:<select name="option">
    <option value="1">Юредическое лицо</option>
    <option value="2">Частное лицо</option>
    </select><br /></form>;         
$option = isset($_GET['option']) ? $_GET['option'] : 1;         
echo $option;
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Как получить выбранный элемент из селекта? В переменную `option`, к примеру.

Comment: Вопрос: что у вас за ерунда написана? Это php код или html?

Comment: поставьте кавычки и echo вам будет php

Comment: *Юредическое* лол

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?
$opt = intval(!empty($_GET['opt']) ? $_GET['opt'] : 0);
if (!$opt) {
?>
<form method="post">
<select name="opt" onchange="this.form.submit()">
  <option value="0" selected="selected">выберите</option>
  <option value="1">Юридическое лицо</option>
  <option value="2">Частное лицо</option>
</select>
</form>
<? } else { ?>
Выбрано: <?=$opt?>
<? } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну для начала я посоветовал бы в форму кнопку submit прикрутить :) Позвольте поинтересоваться, это ваш рабочий код или просто пара неразделенных кусков?

Comment: куски главное как получить, желательно без кнопки, т.е какой сейчас активный тот и получить, через PHP не JS

Comment: вы понимаете вообще как работает http и php в часности?<br>
Если через php - никак... ^^

Comment: без AJAX с JS - никак. Если вам категорически претит - есть еще VB и новомодный Dart. С поддержкой проблемы, но это мелочи

али вам сразу по измению поля отправлять запрос нужно?

Comment: я не могу получить выбранный элемент select при помощи php, что за сказки?

Comment: Бех отправки данных клиентом - не можете, это я, типа, тонко намекаю вам...

Comment: понял о чем говорите.

Comment: аффтар, почитайте известного русского сказочника Котерова, к примеру - оч-чень полезно. охота умыть руки, но все же...
PHP - это серверный, а не браузерный язык, и работать с динамически измененными в браузере данными не умеет - просто не имеет к ним доступа. Без подвязки сторонних средств - совсем никак

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$option = isset($_GET['option']) ? (int) $_GET['option'] : 1;
echo $option;
?>

<form id="formazak" method="get">Контактная информация<br /><br />
Вы заказываете как:
<select name="option">
<option value="1">Юредическое лицо</option>
<option value="2">Частное лицо</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```